# Can't unmap shared memory

Tags: c, ubuntu, posix, shared-memory, mmap

I've succesfully mapped a memory object with a size of an Integer, as such:

```
shared_var = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE  | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shmid, 0);
```

But when I try to unmap it, I either get an error for an invalid argument when I say length is 0, as such:

```
if(munmap(shared_var, 0) == -1){
    perror(NULL);
    printf("Error unmapping memory: %d\n", errno);
    exit(1);
}
```

which prints out:

Invalid Argument

Error unmapping memory: 22

Or I get a segmentation fault when I say length is sizeof(int), as such:

```
if(munmap(shared_var, sizeof(int)) == -1){
    perror(NULL);
    printf("Error unmapping memory: %d\n", errno);
    exit(1);
}
```

Any ideas of why this is hapening?

EDIT: shmid came from the instance of creating the shared memory:

```
if( (shmid = shm_open("/OS",   O_RDWR | O_CREAT ,0700)) == -1){
        printf("Error creating memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ftruncate(shmid, sizeof(int)) == -1){
        printf("Error defining size\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: The [EINVAL is expected](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/munmap.html) when the _len_ argument to `munmap` is zero.  For the segfault, can you please show us a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  There's something you're not showing us, perhaps with _shmid_.

Comment: Are you sure the mapping is successful?  Where's your check against MAP_FAILED (do this before the (int *) cast)?

Comment: will do, 1 minute

Comment: Pretty sure it was successful, I was able to set its value and change throughout my code without any issues... The point of this program is to create an object of shared memory and have several different processes access it and change it.

Comment: the `munmap()` itself cannot be the cause of the SIGSEGV. Perhaps you are trying to access the page after unmapping it

Comment: @Ctx Yes! That was it! The seg fault was not on the munmap(), thank you! Now I'm trying to figure out the other error, but thank you!